# React UseRef and forwardRef issue for an element position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-ref, react-forwardref

I have successfully connected my component `Details.js` in order to manage the state out of the component itself, these are the steps:

You can see the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-fog-hd8pn)

**Details.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, ref, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from "react";

  const cleanValue = () => {
    setDataHomeTeam([]);
    setDataAwayTeam([]);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(fowardedRef, () => {
    return {
      cleanValue: cleanValue
    };
  });

const ConnectedDetails = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  null
)(Details);

export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <ConnectedDetails {...props} fowardedRef={ref} />;
});
```

**App.js**

```
const ref = useRef();  
<button onClick={() => ref.current.cleanValue()} type="button">Reset</button>
<Details ref={ref} />
```

It works ,the demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-fog-hd8pn).

My problem is when i move this element from **App.js** to **Leagues.js** as you can see in the demo ( there are both cases )

**Leagues.js**

Line 71

```
<button onClick={() => ref.current.cleanValue()} type="button">Reset</button>
```

i get this error when i click on it => *TypeError Cannot read property 'cleanValue' of undefined*

Is it possible ? If yes, what am i doing wrong and how can i fix that?

Comment: You’re running into problem again? :)

Comment: It works very well, my issue now is that i am trying now to make the button working inside the League.js and not in App.js. Thanks

Comment: the `ref` in the league's component is never given a value - it's unclear (to me) what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You just simply move your ref creation and still keep setting the ref to the detail component, it’s supposed to be working then

Comment: In `App` you pass the `ref` to `Details` in `League` you don't. Add a `Details` component to the render output and pass it the `ref`.

Comment: Thanks, if you provide the answer with the code i can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the main issue was that the `ref` reference within the `Leagues` component was not pointing to the `Details` component.

The following 3 modifications to your original code can be done to make the button in the `Leagues` component work:

1. Adding an `onReset` property to the `Leagues` component

   ```
    let Leagues = ({
          getList,
          getStats,
          leaguesList,
          loading,
          getDetail,
          teamsDetail,
          onReset
        })
   ```
2. using the `onReset` function in the `Leagues` component

   **Original**:  `<button onClick={() => ref.current.cleanValue()} type="button">`

   **New:**       `<button onClick={onReset} type="button">`
3. setting the `onReset` property of the `Leagues` component to a function which will call the `cleanValue()` method of the `Details` component

   **Original:** `<Leagues />`

   **New:**      `<Leagues onReset={() => ref.current.cleanValue()} />`

The full code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-currying-rtrlo).

Please note that from architectural perspective, it is not recommended for a component to access its sibling via reference. Many scenarios where this seems needed might be better dealt with via the parent component.